# Using a VB.NET DLL file in C++ - class is abstract

Tags: c++, vb.net, abstract-class, dllimport

I created a VB.NET DLL file which I am using in an unmanaged [C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++) project.

When I try to create an object of the class, I am getting an error:

> cannot instantiate abstract class

Why would my class be abstract? How can I modify it so that it won't be abstract?

Comment: How are you using the DLL in your project?   Please post the code where you are actually creating an object from the DLL.

Comment: CComPtr< IWSconnection > pIWSconnection;
 pIWSconnection = pIWSconnection.CoCreateInstance( __uuidof(IWSconnection ) );

I thought this created an object, but then when I tried to call a method from the dll - 
    pIWSconnection.connect(...);
I got an error that pIWSconnenction is an udeclared identifier

So I added this line:
    IWSconnection pIWSconnection;
Which generated the above error...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how it works, you have to write COM code in C++ to use it.  Take a good look at the [#import directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6.aspx) and the smart pointers it creates.